# monodevelop code formatting

Tags: monodevelop

I'm using monodevelop on my mac to develop for iPhone. I was wondering if there is a way to change how MD formats C# code? by default it puts the curly braces at the same line as the if which I personally don't like....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the Solution Options dialog, go to Source Code->Code Formatting->C#. These will cascade to the projects in the solution, but you can override it for individual projects if you want.

You can change the defaults for new solutions in the Default Policies dialog, but this will not affect existing solutions.

Comment: I don't seem to have Source Code in options dialog. I'm using MD on my OSX for MonoTouch. Should I download an addon or something?

Comment: It's in *Solution Options*, not Preferences.

Comment: @mhutch Is there any shortcut for formatting code in Monodevelop as one in VS like Cntrl+K+D

Comment: On Mac, it's Control-K. Not sure offhand what it is on Window but you can find out in the Keybindings preferences/options panel, and change it if you want.

Comment: Might be an idea to mention that the Solution Options dialogue is in the Project menu.

Comment: It's also in the context menu on the solution in the project pad.

Comment: @BhushanFirake On mac in the most recent version of Monodevelop, control-i will apply your autoformatting policy to the open document.

Answer (score 1):

- Choose Preferences from Edit
- Under Text Editor choose Behavior
- Uncheck Enable on the fly formatting

Comment: THIS is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: I didn't find `Preferences` in the `Edit` menu. I had to go to `Tools` -> `Options`. This was on Windows 10, MonoDevelop 5.9.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a custom policy, save it to a file, share it with your team (they'll need to import the policy), and then quickly select it from Solution Options.